# Reporting services SSL fix

Tags: reporting-services

Hi how can i fix this error:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

When i click on Report Manager URL i get this error. I tried to run IE and Chrome as Administrator but i still get this error.I read a little bit about this problem and someone suggesting to add a certificate. But how i can do that and why i need certicicate .I was running reporting services before without certificate